# What's the best way in Ruby to average sets in an array?

Tags: ruby

Given the following simple data set, what is the best way to average the values for the sets 0 25 53 and 80.

```
  [["0", "148.5"],
   ["0", "146.5"],
   ["0", "148.6"],
   ["0", "202.3"],
   ["25", "145.7"],
   ["25", "145.5"],
   ["25", "147.4"],
   ["25", "147.3"],
   ["53", "150.4"],
   ["53", "147.6"],
   ["53", "147.8"],
   ["53", "215.4"],
   ["80", "150.4"],
   ["80", "149.4"],
   ["80", "148.0"],
   ["80", "149.9"]]
```

Comment: Can you rephrase?  I don't understand what you're asking.  An example answer would be helpful.

Comment: Jason's code returns exaclty what I'm looking for:
{"80"=>149.425, "25"=>146.475, "0"=>161.475, "53"=>165.3}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's simple enough with inject. I often implement a general group_by method in projects to help with stuff like this.

If data is large and performance matters consider using a numeric library or database if appropriate.

```
data = [ ... ]

groups = data.inject({}) do |hash, pair| 
  hash[pair.first] ||= []
  hash[pair.first] << pair.last.to_f
  hash
end

groups.inject({}) do |hash, pair| 
  hash[pair.first] = pair.last.inject(0,&:+) / pair.last.size
  hash
end
```

Comment: brilliant! can you explain, or point to some docs for &:+ ? I didn't know inject took arguments in addition to the initial value and the block, or is that the block!?! Whoa, I think you just blew my mind!

Comment: That's the block: http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2006/3/7/symbol-to-proc-shorthand

 `&:foo` is syntactic sugar for `:foo.to_proc`. `Symbol#to_proc` happens to be conveniently written to wrap a method send in a `Proc` object.

It's nice shorthand, but be aware that it does have a performance overhead compared to the longhand, so don't use it in performance critical inner loops.

Comment: Doh, apologize for the markdown clutter, didn't realize comments weren't filtered the same as answers.

Answer (score 1):

Using inject with a hash will yield poor performance (you're re-assigning the memo var at every iteration). If you're on 1.9, Enumerable implements the method `group_by`, which can be used to make the code a little more obvious:

```
result = array.map{ |row| [row.first.to_i, row.last.to_f] }.group_by(&:first)
result.each_pair do |key, values|
  result[key] = values.average
end
```

`Array#average` is easily implemented as

```
class Array
  def average
    inject(0.0) { |sum, e| sum + e } / length
  end
end
```

The fact that your data is strings is quite inconvenient, I recommend avoiding that whenever possible.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "re-assigning the memo var at every iteration"? The calls are done by reference, so assigning the variable will involve the same overhead no matter the type of the value.