# averaging values embedded in ruby hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash

I have an embedded hash, for which i need to calculate averages.  I've already grouped them, successfully, (from ungrouped) but finding the average isn't working for me

Here is the example hash data

```
myhash = {"2011-02-15"=>[["2011-02-15", 10], ["2011-02-15", 60]], 
          "2011-02-22"=>[["2011-02-22", 22]], 
          "2011-02-28"=>[["2011-02-28", 110],["2011-02-28", 70]]}
```

here is how I grouped them  (they used to be just {k => v} ungrouped)

```
@r = @myhash.group_by(&:first)
```

I tried both solutions from this thread ([What's the best way in Ruby to average sets in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880268/whats-the-best-way-in-ruby-to-average-sets-in-an-array))  but neither worked.

good question.  I want the results to be averaged by date, so I can serve them up that way.

```
[{"2012-02-15" => 35"}, {"2012-02-22" => 22"}, {"2012-02-28" => 90"}]
```

Comment: How is averaging a bunch of strings defined? What do you want the result to be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Hash[myhash.map { |k,v| [k, v.map(&:last).inject(:+) / v.size] }]
#=> {"2011-02-15"=>35, "2011-02-22"=>22, "2011-02-28"=>90}
```

Comment: Wow. Can you explain how inject is working in this case? I tough it expected an object and a block.

Comment: @ismaelga `inject` can take a symbol for a method to "inject" between each value, calling that method on the `memo` with the current element. So `inject(:+)` gets expanded to `inject { |memo, obj| memo.+(obj) }`. When you don't give `inject` an initial value, it just uses the first element. The [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) are worth reading `:)`.

Comment: I did read but I didn't understood. Thanks for your explanation. But how is it different from `reduce(:+)` in this case?

Comment: @ismaelga No difference, [`reduce` is aliased to `inject`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v1_9_3_194/enum.c#L2683), so use of one over the other is merely preference.

Comment: Oh, thanks Andrew, that makes sense. Just a add for semantics I guess

Comment: @ismaelga Well, also, the `inject` (and all other "-ect" methods e.g. `select`, `reject`, `collect`) name comes from Smalltalk, whereas the aliased names come from functional languages.

Answer (score 0):

In rails, `Array` class has a `sum` method. You can use it as follows:

**Approach 1**

```
{}.tap{ |h| myhash.each{ |date, list| h[date] = list.sum(&:last)/list.size}
```

**Approach 2**

```
Hash[myhash.map{ |date, list| [date, list.sum(&:last)/list.size] }]
```